# Sharing Console Application object to Self-Host WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to share my application statistics via a wcf service. I'm able to self-host my wcf service but ServiceHost object constructor is default leaving me to unable to initialize other member variables of my service.

Sample:

```
public interface IService
{
   //some operations here 
}

public class Service : IService
{
  object myObject;
  //implementation of IService
}
```

myObject is my console application object ( List ) and I wanted to make my service to be able to look into it. Is there any way I can reference it on my WCF Service?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide an instance of the service yourself by [creating](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx) a custom [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx).

Comment: I'll try the IInstanceProvider. Do I need to add something on my app.config file? The sample on the link uses a class that implements IContractBehaviorAttribute, IContractBehavior but it does not show how it was instantiated. 

I'm hosting my service like this:
ServiceHost dccaService = new ServiceHost(typeof(CreditControl.SOA.SOAP.Service));

dccaService.Open();

Comment: An `IServiceBehavior` is needed in order to register the custom instance provider. Then you could also have a custom `ServiceHost`. Here's another link that demonstrates the whole process: http://initializecomponent.blogspot.com/2008/06/integrating-unity-with-wcf.html

Comment: I've created a class that implements IServiceBehavior, a class that implements IInstanceProvider and a class that implements IContractBehaviorAttribute and IContractBehavior. 

The creation of my service will be the same just like I posted above. I'm expecting my class the implements IServiceBehavior will be available on SvcConfigEditor.exe under extension when I navigate my dll file but it is not. Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach to the get handle on your `ServiceHost` instance in your service implementation code:

```
ServiceHostBase base = OperationContext.Current.Host;
```

Now you have a link to to your service host - anything publicly available and accessible can be read (preferably not set, since there might be many service class instances running).